# Listing a job that moved to another city in a different country on my resume

Tags: resume

Last year I started a new job in City A, and after a few months I was internally transferred to City B in a different country. My job responsibilities remain the same, so I am wondering **how to include the fact that I've worked in two different cities on my resume**?

Since A and B are not in the same country, I feel that it is relevant to include the fact I've worked in both, I'm just not sure how to state this on my resume.

Comment: Well... at the place were you put the location for a job you hold you put two cities instead of one. And I think it would also make sense to add one sentence to the job description in the end explaining it.

Comment: While I think the broader question has merit on its own, is it important to list City A if you were only there for a few months? Presumably you worked in Country A prior to this job?

Comment: @Lilienthal Both cities are outside of my native country

Answer (score 3):

> **Job Title**
>
> AlphaWidgets Ltd
>
> Someville, Silvania - May 2015 to Jan 2016
>
> Whostowne, Krakozia - Jan 2016 to Now

Not much else to do...